# Desktop comes very slowly after I push power button

Tags: kubuntu

Opening is very slow.I wait your suggestions.My kubuntu is setuped on ssd.

```
ahmet@ahmet:~$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 7.298s (kernel) + 34.948s (userspace) = 42.246s
graphical.target reached after 34.938s in userspace
ahmet@ahmet:~$ systemd-analyze blame
30.049s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
2.404s dev-sda2.device
1.742s tor@default.service
1.304s snapd.service
1.240s dev-loop0.device
1.211s dev-loop1.device
1.201s dev-loop2.device
1.174s dev-loop3.device
1.010s systemd-journal-flush.service
788ms mpd.service
784ms systemd-udevd.service
646ms systemd-logind.service
640ms avahi-daemon.service
636ms lm-sensors.service
630ms pppd-dns.service
608ms NetworkManager.service
583ms ModemManager.service
568ms networkd-dispatcher.service
483ms udisks2.service
457ms grub-common.service
448ms systemd-resolved.service
420ms systemd-timesyncd.service
393ms accounts-daemon.service
392ms gpu-manager.service
384ms wpa_supplicant.service
372ms rsyslog.service
344ms apparmor.service
268ms upower.service
224ms phpsessionclean.service
222ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-B044\x2d884E.service
189ms thermald.service
187ms apport.service
177ms swapdosya.swap
175ms swapfile.swap
156ms alsa-restore.service
156ms keyboard-setup.service
155ms bluetooth.service
145ms systemd-rfkill.service
137ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
113ms systemd-journald.service
111ms polkit.service
lines 1-41
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that:

```
ahmet@ahmet:~$ systemd-analyze blame
30.049s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

You have configured one (or more) of your network interfaces to "`Require IPv4 (or IPv6) addressing for this connection to be complete`" (in the `IPv4 Settings` or ``` IPv6 Settings`` tabs, or you've configured one of the "Automatic" choices in the ```General` tab; AND it takes half a minute to make the connection.

You should also look at `journalctl -b 0` and compare the interline timestamps, to see finer detail on your problem.